# How do you access a users session from a service in Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony

Does anyone know how to access the session variable in a service?

I have a service setup that I pass the container over to. I can access things like the Doctrine service by using:

```
// Get the doctrine service
$doctrine_service = $this->container->get('doctrine');  
// Get the entity manager
$em = $doctrine_service->getEntityManager();
```

However, I'm not sure how to access the session.

In a controller the session can be accessed using:

```
$session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
$session->set('foo', 'bar');
$foo = $session->get('foo');
```

Is the session part of a service and if so what is the service called.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`php app/console container:debug` shows that the `session` service is a class instanceof `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session`, so you should be able to retrieve the session with that name:

```
$session = $this->container->get('session');
```

After you've done your work on the session, call `$session->save();` to write everything back to the session. Incidentally, there are two other session-related services that show in my container dump, as well:

`session.storage` instanceof `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\SessionStorage\NativeSessionStorage`

`session_listener` instanceof `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\SessionListener`

Comment: Hi Problematic, thanks for your quick reply. I tried the `$session = $this->container->get('session');` and although it worked it doesn't seem to save anything to the session. Do I need to do anything to pass the updated session data back?

Comment: I checked out the Session class, and it has a `save()` method. Try a call to that, see if it works for you.

Comment: Genius! That has worked a treat. Thanks for all your help Problematic!

Comment: So, to set the session is $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
$session->set('foo', 'bar'); $session->save(); and to retrieve the session in another controller is $session = $this->container->get('session'); ?

Answer (score 58):

If you don't want to pass in the entire container you simply pass in @session in the arguments:

**services.yml**

```
my.service:
    class: MyApp\Service
    arguments: ['@session']
```

**Service.php**

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;

class Service
{

    private $session;

    public function __construct(Session $session)
    {
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    public function someService()
    {
        $sessionVar = $this->session->get('session_var');
    }

}
```

Comment: Hello! I'm new in SF2 and I'm trying to figure out how the sessions works.. could you tell me how  can I set or get the sessions in the controller using this service please?

Comment: Hi, from the controller you can access the entire 'service container'. So to get the session, you can do `$session = $this->container->get('session');` Likewise any other service you need you can get the same way.

Comment: Starting with Symfony when all you have ever written is raw procedural PHP is tricky. I highly recommend you find a good tutorial of building a basic app start to finish and work through that, it will give you a much better idea of what things do and how to structure your app.

Comment: Great, I'm a Laravel developer and when start using symfony two months ago, was very different.. more "complicated" but thanks for the advice!

Comment: This is the better way to do what the OP asked to do. Instead of directly trying to access the session object from the service, it's better to inject it into the service. This is how I do it.

Answer (score 3):

In Symfony 4, if you have your services configured to autowire you do not need to inject the session manually through `services.yaml` any longer.

Instead you would simply inject the session interface:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface;

class SessionService
{
    private $session;

    public function __construct(
        SessionInterface $session
    )
    {
        $this->session = $session;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;

$session = new Session();
$session->get('variable');
```

Answer (score -2):

faz assim que vai funcionar

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;

class ClassType extends AbstractType {
    private $session;

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

        $this->session = new Session();

    ->add('field', $this->session->get('nameFieldSession'));

    }

}
```

Comment: Please write in English.