# How to set and destroy sessions in PHP Symfony

Tags: php, session, symfony1

How to set and destroy a session on the controller side?
Tried in the view side, works just fine. But now need it from inside the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I found the solution just here around. Use the "session" service explained here: [Old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7192916/how-do-you-access-a-users-session-from-a-service-in-symfony2)

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE:

Destroy a Session in Symfony 2 as follows:

```
$request->getSession()->invalidate(1);
```

As invalidate leaves the current session untouched if you are not providing any parameter you have to set the lifetime on 1 (one second)

Symfony 3.4 documentation:
http://api.symfony.com/3.4/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Session.html#method_invalidate

Answer (score 1):

Did you try?

```
/** @var $session Session */
$session = $request->getSession();
$session->remove('name');
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
$this->getAttributeHolder()->remove('foo');
```

if it was saved in namespace foobar

$user->getAttributeHolder()->remove('foobar','','foo');

Comment: Apparently that did not solve the problem, and what about creating sessions?