# Symfony, session always return null

Tags: php, symfony, session

I'm checking this post [How do you access a users session from a service in Symfony2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7192916/how-do-you-access-a-users-session-from-a-service-in-symfony2) to manage the session in Symfony. I want to set a session variable once the user enters specific information and get the session variable in another controller or even in a twig template, so ...

I have this in my controller:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session;

class MyFirstController
{
    public function myFunction(Request $request)
    {
        $session =  $this->container->get('session');

        $session->set('user', array(
            'name' => 'My Name',
            'email' => 'fake@email.com'
        ));

        $session->save();

         var_dump($session->get('user')); //Print null
    }


}
```

**Another controller:**

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session;

class MySecondController
{
    public function myFunction()
    {
        $session =  $this->container->get('session');

        var_dump($session->get('user')); //Print null
    }


}
```

Even trying to access the session variable after `$session->save();` returns **null**

Hope you can help me.

**Edit**

Using `$session = $request->getSession();` or `$session = $this->container->get('session');` returns the same instance of the session on both.

**config.yml**

```
session:
    handler_id: session.handler.native_file
    save_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/sessions"
```

Another thing is, if I don't use $session->save(); and after set the session do $session->get('user'); it returns the value of  the user, but If I reload the page and try again, now the session is null.

Comment: So let me get this straight, you set `user` field on session, and get `agent` field, and you're wondering why it returns `null`?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.. I fixed the error... it's user not agent.

Comment: Do you have any errors related to sessions logged in error's log?

Comment: FYI, you've got a syntax error where you set the `user` array. You're missing a closing parenthesis but I suspect this is just a typo.

Comment: Did you see your logs? Are there any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store your sessions under accessible for writing directory.

Comment: Did you see my comment?
I think that you have wrong configuration for your sessions and they cannot be stored.

Comment: I think that your `%kernel.root_dir%/sessions` is not writable

Comment: Maybe not because I have a folder inside app like this: app/sessions/sess_6dfget345fdger35 but the file is empty.

Comment: When it was modified? Maybe you just have this file and have no access to it?

Comment: Well, I have not checked all the time but I think I have access all the time to this file but always has been empty

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem using the standard path to store the sessions **var/lib/php/session**

```
framework:
    session:
        save_path: ~
```

And that's all, now I can use the session in another controller even in a twig template.

Thanks to all for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Session inside controller actions can be gotten in either of two ways:

1. `$this->getRequest()->getSession()`
2. `$request->getSession()`