# Service in symfony2 - how service file should look like?

Tags: symfony

I am trying to create service in `symfony2` which will verify if session contains certain information and if not redirect the user to another controller. I want this piece of code to work as a service as I will be using it in many controllers.

I have problem as manual on Symfony2 book does not provide information how service file should look like. Should it be a normal php class?

Please find below dump of my files with information on error that I receive.

In `\AppBundle\Services` I create file `my_isbookchosencheck.php` containing:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\my_isbookchosencheck;

class my_isbookchosencheck
{
    public function __construct();
    {
        $session = new Session();
        $session->getFlashBag()->add('msg', 'No book choosen. Redirected to proper form');
        if(!$session->get("App_Books_Chosen_Lp")) return new RedirectResponse($this->generateUrl('app_listbooks'));
    }
}
```

My `service.yml`:

```
my_isbookchosencheck:
        class:         AppBundle\Services\my_isbookchosencheck
```

My conntroller file:

```
/**
        * This code is aimed at checking if the book is choseen and therefore whether any further works may be carried out
        */
        $checker = $this->get('my_isbookchosencheck');
```

Error:

```
FileLoaderLoadException in FileLoader.php line 125: There is no extension able to load the configuration for "my_isbookchosencheck" (in C:/wamp/www/symfony_learn/app/config\services.yml). Looked for namespace "my_isbookchosencheck", found "framework", "security", "twig", "monolog", "swiftmailer", "assetic", "doctrine", "sensio_framework_extra", "fos_user", "knp_paginator", "genemu_form", "debug", "acme_demo", "web_profiler", "sensio_distribution" in C:/wamp/www/symfony_learn/app/config\services.yml (which is being imported from "C:/wamp/www/symfony_learn/app/config\config.yml").
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few mistakes that you made, which I am going to explain in short, and I will give you an example of the service you want to create.

- You created your service in `AppBundle\Services`, yet your namespace is registered differently - `namespace AppBundle\Services\my_isbookchosencheck;`. It should be `namespace AppBundle\Services;`. I would also advise you to use singular names when creating directories - in this case `Service` would be better, instead of `Services`.
- You're using your `__constructor` directly to apply some logic and return the result of it. Better way would be to create a custom method, which could be accessed when necessary.
- You're creating new instance of `Session` which means that you wont be able to access anything that was previously added and stored in session. The right way here, would be to inject `RequestStack` which holds the current `Request` and get the session from there.
- I believe you also registered your service wrong. In your `services.yml` file, it should be under `services:` option. This is why you got the error you pasted.

So, let's see how your service should like.

**services.yml**

```
services:
    book_service:
        class: AppBundle\Service\BookService
        arguments:
            - @request_stack
            - @router
```

**BookService.php**

```
namespace AppBundle\Service;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;

class BookService {

    /* @var $request Request */
    private $request;

    /* @var $router RouterInterface */
    private $router;

    public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack, RouterInterface $router) {
        $this->request = $requestStack->getCurrentRequest();
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    public function isBookChoosen() {
        $session = $this->request->getSession();

        // Now you can access session the proper way.
        // If anything was added in session from your controller
        // you can access it here as well.

        // Apply your logic here and use $this->router->generate()
    }

}
```

Now in your controller you can simply use it like this:

```
$this->get('book_service')->isBookChoosen()
```

Well this is a short example, but I hope you got the idea.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
services:    
    my_isbookchosencheck:
        class:         AppBundle\Services\my_isbookchosencheck
```

in your services.yml, and check that you use the correct namespaces.

Your Class is fine and it should work, however may i suggest that you use
symfony2 session service instead of creating the session object yourself, you can pass it as a constructor argument:

```
<?php

// namespace edited
namespace AppBundle\Services;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;

class my_isbookchosencheck
{
    public function __construct(Session $session);
    {
        $session->getFlashBag()->add('msg', 'No book choosen. Redirected to proper form');
        if(!$session->get("App_Books_Chosen_Lp")) return new RedirectResponse($this->generateUrl('app_listbooks'));
    }
}
```

and then edit your services.yml accordingly, so the service container will inject the session object:

```
services:    
    my_isbookchosencheck:
        class:         AppBundle\Services\my_isbookchosencheck
        arguments:     [@session]
```

Also check out his question on so:
[How do you access a users session from a service in Symfony2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7192916/how-do-you-access-a-users-session-from-a-service-in-symfony2)

Answer (score 1):

Services are just regular PHP classes, nothing special. But you must register it in order to be recognized by the system. Here are the steps how you do it,

Create a regular PHP class (you can inject other services if it requires)

```
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Service;

class MyService
{
    private $session;

    public function _construct(SessionInterface $session /* here we're injecting the session service which implements the SessionInterface */)
    {
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    // other methods go here, which holds the business logic of this class
}
```

ok, we created a class, we need to register it to be able to use it by service container, here how you do it:

the simplest way is to put it into `config.yml` file, like this:

```
services:
    my_service:
        class: Acme\DemoBundle\Service\MyService
        arguments:
           - @session
```

or, another way, is to create a file (e.g. `services.yml`, may be in `config` folder), and import it inside the `config.yml` file (the content of the file is the same as the first way):

```
imports:
    - { resource: services.yml }
```

or, you can create a `services.yml`(the content of the file is the same as the first way) file inside you bundle's `Resources` folder, specify it under the `load` method of your Extension class (under the DependencyInjection folder), **(this way requires some special directory and file structure, read about it in the doc)**:

```
class AcmeDemoExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $loader = new YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__ . '/../Resources'));
        $loader->load('services.yml');
    }
}
```

**In you case**, you're not registering your service, the service container just couldn't find it. Register it by one of the above ways.